# Matplotlib Multiple-Lined Plot using CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, mcmc

I have created my own MCMC affine invariant algorithm using two dimensions, slope and y-intercept, and also using 4 walkers. I have all of data in a csv file where there are two columns m and b, and then for every first of four rows, it would represent the first walker. So for instance, with the csv file below, the first walker is represented in the 0th, 4th, 8th, and 12th rows while the second walker is represented in the 1st, 5th, 9th, and 13th rows, and so on.  A snippet of what it looks like is below:

[image: chain.csv]

I want to create a plot that looks like a spaghetti or evolution plot https://python-graph-gallery.com/124-spaghetti-plot/ where each of the walkers are represented by their own line rather than the entire column of m and b being plotted as their own line. So far I have a function that separates the walker by row and column by data frames but I am having trouble plotting these values as multiple lines.

```
def make_evo_plot(df):
   w1m = df['m'][0::4] #walker1 m
   w1b = df['b'][0::4] #walker1 b
   w2m = df['m'][1::4] #walker2 m
   w2b = df['b'][1::4] #walker2 b
   w3m = df['m'][2::4] #walker3 m
   w3b = df['b'][2::4] #walker3 b
   w4m = df['m'][3::4] #walker4 m
   w4b = df['b'][3::4] #walker4 b
   fig,ax = plt.subplots()
   plt.plot(w1m)
   plt.plot(w2m)
   plt.plot(w3m)
   plt.plot(w4m)
   ax.plot(w1b,w2b,w3b,w4b)
   plt.show()
```

And from this code, my plot looks like this:
[image: bad plot]

Any help in plotting the data is greatly appreciated!!

**Update:**
I tried doing the below code but I get `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (0,) and (8750,)`

```
def make_evo_plot(df):
  w1m = df['m'][0::4] #walker1 m
  w1b = df['b'][0::4] #walker1 b
  w2m = df['m'][1::4] #walker2 m
  w2b = df['b'][1::4] #walker2 b
  w3m = df['m'][2::4] #walker3 m
  w3b = df['b'][2::4] #walker3 b
  w4m = df['m'][3::4] #walker4 m
  w4b = df['b'][3::4] #walker4 b
  fig,ax = plt.subplots()
  plt.plot(w1m)
  plt.plot(w2m)
  plt.plot(w3m)
  plt.plot(w4m)
  ax.plot(w1b,w2b,w3b,w4b)
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

To plot the evolution of the slopes/intercepts just Define a sequence for your axis like `x=np.arange(0,100,5)` and then use `ax.plot(x, w1m)`

```
def make_evo_plot(df):
   w1m = df['m'][0::4] #walker1 m
   w1b = df['b'][0::4] #walker1 b
   w2m = df['m'][1::4] #walker2 m
   w2b = df['b'][1::4] #walker2 b
   w3m = df['m'][2::4] #walker3 m
   w3b = df['b'][2::4] #walker3 b
   w4m = df['m'][3::4] #walker4 m
   w4b = df['b'][3::4] #walker4 b

   x = np.arange(0,2500,5) #Define a sequence of same length as your data

   fig,ax = plt.subplots()

   #To plot the evolution of the 4 slopes
   ax.plot(x,w1m)
   ax.plot(x,w2m)
   ax.plot(x,w3m)
   ax.plot(x,w4m)

   plt.show()
```

Comment: I changed `x = np.arange(0,2500,5)` since I have 10,000 values and then divided by the 4 walkers is 2500 but I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8750,) (500,) ` and it references the panda package

Comment: Just to clarify you want 10,000 lines?

Comment: No, I want 4 lines but I have a total of 10,000 values of slopes and y-intercepts

Comment: So to clarify you went the evolution of those slopes and intercepts which are sequential.

Comment: Yes, so that there are four lines as it relates to each walker

Comment: See edit for a plot of the slopes. You can do the same thing for the y-intercepts but you will want to do this on a different plot because your values are too different and your slopes will show up as straight horizontal lines.